# UICollectionViewCell alpha value on Rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with a custom `UICollectionViewCell`. I set the `alpha` property in the `UICollectionViewCell` to `0.0f` for a speific task which all works as expected.  However, when I rotate the view to landscape the cell's `alpha` resets itself to `1.0`.

I've played around with this and the collection view holds the state of selected cells and removed cells etc. but not the alpha value of the cell.

I have tried to re-set the alpha values of the changed cells on `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`, which it does but then changes it back to `1.0` once that call has completed.

I'm trying to figure out where the alpha value of the `UICollectionViewCell` is resetting itself after it rotates.

If I run the below code I get the desired alpha values back for the cells, however at some point after this they all change back to `1.0`:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
    //array containing IndexPaths for cells with 0.0f alpha value
    for (NSIndexPath *path in self.selectedlettersArray) {
        LetterCellView* lsv = (LetterCellView*) [self.collectionView     cellForItemAtIndexPath:path];
        lsv.alpha = 0.0f; 
    }

    for (LetterCellView *lsv in self.collectionView.visibleCells) {

        NSLog(@"After Cell Alpha is : %f", lsv.alpha);

    } 
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In collection views the alpha - along with other properties - is not reliably managed via the usual view properties, at least this is not intended.

Instead, you should use the `alpha` property of `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` object that is managed by the `UICollectionReusableView` class via `applyLayoutAttributes:`.

Read up on this in the
[UICollectionReusableView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/Reference/Reference.html) and the
[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Hi Mundi, Thnaks for your response.  I tried to set the alpha property  using the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes which worked fine when I initially set the alpha to 0, but on rotate it went back to 1.  Any other ideas what could be the issue?

Comment: Did you try a simple `reloadData` or `setNeedsDisplay`?

Comment: Yes, it makes the change in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:, then changes it to 1.0 at some point after that call.  I think it's probably not the best way yo do what I am trying to do, so I'm look at re-designing how I am using the collectionview.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Aah - the state of the alpha is NOT in your data model. That is the problem. Never use the state of a view to "store" something.

Comment: Ah, Now I get it.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Based on Mundi's suggestion that the UICollectionViewCell alpha property is not reliable managed, I ended up adding a property to my custom UICollectionViewCell to set it to visible or hidden.  Where I just set the cell's content (in my case a label) alpha to 0 or 1.

This now sticks when I rotate the device, although it seems like a bit of a workaround.