# Load a UICollectionViewCell with different alpha value than its UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am having trouble giving my `UICollectionViewCell` a different alpha than the `UICollectionView` that owns them. I have looked at a few other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092463/uicollectionviewcell-alpha-value-on-rotate) but none have worked for me. I have a .xib file with the `UICollectionView` where the alpha is set to 0.9, and the cells inside are loaded from another .xib file with their alpha set to 1.0. The `UICollectionView`'s alpha takes precedence no matter what I have tried. These attempts include:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell

// Here is the first attempt
    cell.alpha = 1.0
    cell.contentView.alpha = 1.0

// Here is the second attempt
    let attribute = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
    attribute.alpha = 1.0
    cell.applyLayoutAttributes(attribute)

    cell.setNeedsDisplay()
    return cell
```

I want the cells to load with no transparency, but I want the collection view housing them to be slightly transparent. There is a unique image loaded on each cell that cannot be transparent at all.

Edit1: I tried setting the `backgroundColor` of the `UICollectionView` to clear with a 1.0 alpha, then giving it a custom `backgroundView` in my `viewDidLoad()` method. I have an `@IBOutlet` of the collection view that I use to set the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

// MARK: -View Lifecycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    let background = UIView(frame: collectionView.bounds)
    background.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 26/255.0, green: 26/255.0, blue: 26/255.0, alpha: 0.97)
    collectionView.backgroundView = background

    collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "Cell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

}
```

This DID work.

Comment: you want the collectionView to have an alpha value of 0.9 and the collectionViewCells a value of 1.0?

Comment: Yeah! The collectionView has an alpha of 0.9 and it's giving the cells that same alpha.

Comment: try to set a background view to the collection view , and than change it's alpha. Hope this will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t have parent view with alpha != 1 and its childs with alpa=1, they wont work as expected.

Usually what i do is use an aux view (same frame as the collection View), sibling of the parent (your collection view) view with the alpha set to X value. Set the  collection view background's color to clearColor.

Comment: Please see my edit. I'm afraid I might not be doing this correctly?